# Get SCONS Substfile to replace a key with a value of "${SOMETHING}"

Tags: scons

I'm working with SCONS and using the Substfile() to generate a new file from a template.  I provide a replacement dictionary via the SUBST_DICT parameter of Substfile().

In my replacement dictionary, I've got a key "@DUMMY@" that has a value of "${SOMETHING}".

When SCONS does the replacement, @DUMMY@ is replaced with a blank.  How do I get it to fill in ${SOMETHING} instead?

I've tried various escapes:
"\${SOMETHING}": invalid escape sequence
"\${SOMETHING}": replaces with "\${SOMETHING}"

Answer (score 2):

Just found the answer in some Python docs.  Escaping the value with an extra $ resolved the problem.

So setting "@DUMMY@" equal to "$${SOMETHING}" resolved the problem.